# how to find files in multiple symbolic link

Tags: linux, shell, find

I am trying to find files from  multiple link folders in UNIX and LINUX. I have following scenario

I have two folders ntLLN1/lln1 and ntLLN2/lln2.

ntLLN1/lln1 contains two files as below:

ID420.data
ID3345.data

ntLLN2/lln2 contains three files as follow:

ID21.data
ID3456.data
ID56709.data

now I have created symbolic link for ntLLN2/lln2 and ntLLN2/lln2 called LN1 and LN2.. so Now LN1 also has link for below two files:

ID420.data
ID3345.data

LN2 contians link for below three files

ID21.data
ID3456.data
ID56709.final

Now I wish to use find command to find files in all LN folders i.e. in LN1 and LN2 (link folders)

Required output from LN folders

./LN1/lln1/ID420.data
./LN1/lln1/ID3345.data
./LN2/lln2/ID21.data
./LN2/lln2/ID3456.data
./LN2/lln2/ID56709.final

I have used below command but it finds only in LN1 and it does not list the content of LN2

find ./LN* -follow -name "*ID*"

Please give some suggestion as I am new to Linux and Shell script and I wish to use that in shell script. I need to run this on UNIX and LINUX server

Answer (score 0):

You want `-name 'ID*'` to find files matching that pattern.

However, with this bug you would also not have found any files in `LN1`. Are you sure this is the command you used?